# after importing speech component, cannot find it in the palette

Tags: delphi, components, activex

I have tried several times importing the Microsoft speech component, as described in Brian Long's article. After the import, it does create a unit as part of my newly created project, but I cannot find it on the palette, so I cannot drop the component on the form. I have tried installing it on the standard palette, and also used the default "ActiveX". If is not on the standard palette when I try that, and I cannot find an ActiveX palette in the list of categories. Any know how to find the ActiveX palette? Thank you.

I am trying to Import a Type Library.
MY answers to 2 users that replied: I am using Delphi 10.3.  I am checking the "generate component wrappers".

Comment: What Delphi version are you using? Anything relatively new (2005 and up) allows you to search the component palette. There is also an ActiveX tab in the palette on every Delphi installation I've ever done since around Delphi 2 or so.

Comment: Did you enable the option to generate a component when importing the ActiveX control?

Comment: I cannot find anyplace where there is a component for "Speech" to drop on my form after I import it. I did find an ActiveX area on the palette after I import the component, under "Delphi|  Windows, but there are no components to add to the form." When is the name of the component I need, and where in the Palette do I find it?